# Go.js Check Box not coming with table

Tags: javascript, gojs

Hello I have developed a code in which MynodeTemplate look like

```
GO(go.Node, "Auto",
        GO(go.Shape,
                  new go.Binding("fill", "boxcolor")),
                  GO(go.Panel, "Table",
                    { defaultAlignment: go.Spot.Left, margin: 4 },
                    GO(go.RowColumnDefinition, { column: 1, width: 4 }),
                    GO(go.TextBlock,
                      { row: 0, column: 0, columnSpan: 3, alignment: go.Spot.Center },
                      { font: "bold 12pt sans-serif" },
                      new go.Binding("text", "name")),
                      //Checkbox code 
                      GO(go.TextBlock, "Meta Item : ",
                        { row: 1, column: 0 }),
                    GO(go.TextBlock,
                      { row: 1, column: 2 },
                        new go.Binding("text", "MetaItemName")),
                    GO(go.TextBlock, "Perspective: ",
                                 { row: 2, column: 0 }),
                    GO(go.TextBlock,
                      { row: 2, column: 2 },
                    new go.Binding("text", "PerspectiveName")),

                  ),
                  new go.Binding("scale", "scale").makeTwoWay(),
                  new go.Binding("font", "font").makeTwoWay(),
                  new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
                  new go.Binding("locationSpot", "dir", function(d) { return spotConverter(d, false); })
                );
```

and UI look like

[image]

I want to put one checkbox beside my first name so I have code like

```
GO("CheckBox","name",{row:1,column:1}),
```

but it's not coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me, except that you set the **RowColumnDefinition.width** of column 1 to be 4, which is really too narrow for a checkbox.  Changing that width of 4 to be 14 wide results in:
[image: checkbox in Table Panel]

Note that if the user checks the "CheckBox", it modifies the `data.name` property, because that is the property name that you gave in the definition of the "CheckBox".  But you also have the first **TextBlock** bound to the `data.name` property, which is why in the second node the title/header text has been changed to "true".

By the way, I didn't see this question about GoJS until now because you tagged with "go.js" rather than "gojs".  I suggest that you remove/delete the "go.js" tag and tag this with "gojs".